# What is the difference between fork() and vfork()?

Tags: c, unix, fork, vfork

What is the difference between [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) and [`vfork()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vfork.2.html)? Does `vfork()` return like `fork()`.

Comment: *fork* means Functions On Real Kernels.  *vfork* means Vicariously Functions On Real Kernels.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The intent of `vfork` was to eliminate the overhead of copying the whole process image if you only want to do an `exec*` in the child. Because `exec*` replaces the whole image of the child process, there is no point in copying the image of the parent.

```
if ((pid = vfork()) == 0) {
  execl(..., NULL); /* after a successful execl the parent should be resumed */
  _exit(127); /* terminate the child in case execl fails */
}
```

For other kinds of uses, `vfork` is dangerous and unpredictable.

With most current kernels, however, including Linux, the primary benefit of `vfork` has disappeared because of the way `fork` is implemented. Rather than copying the whole image when `fork` is executed, copy-on-write techniques are used.

Comment: BSD-based systems still have a real *vfork* function.  Read the source.

Comment: Linux has also a real `vfork(2)`. In general, I'd guess every *nix which has been ported to non-MMU platforms has a real `vfork(2)`.

Comment: Important to note *copy-on-write techniques*. Memory gets copied over only if new process tries to modify it. very critical for systems like Android.

Answer (score 31):

As already stated, the `vfork` man page is clear about the differences.
This [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856255/the-difference-between-fork-vfork-exec-and-clone) gives a good description of `fork`, `vfork`, `clone` and `exec`.

Below are some often overlooked differences between `fork` and `vfork` I experienced on some Linux 2.6.3x embedded systems I worked with.

Even with copy-on-write techniques, `fork` fails if you don't have enough memory to duplicate the memory used by the parent process. For example, if the parent process uses 2 GB of resident memory (ie, memory that is used and not just allocated), `fork` fails if you have less than 2 GB of free memory left. That's frustrating when you just want to `exec` a simple program and therefore will never need that huge parent address space!

`vfork` doesn't have this memory issue, as it doesn't duplicate the parent address space. The child process acts more like a thread in which you are able to call `exec*` or `_exit` without hurting your parent process.

Because memory page tables are not duplicated, `vfork` is much faster than `fork` and `vfork`'s  execution time is not affected by the amount of memory the parent process uses, as pointed out here: http://blog.famzah.net/2009/11/20/fork-gets-slower-as-parent-process-use-more-memory/

In situations where performance is critical and/or memory limited, `vfork` + `exec*` can therefore be a good alternative to `fork` + `exec*`. The problem is that it is less safe and the man page says `vfork` is likely to become deprecated in the future.

A safer and more portable solution may be to look at the `posix_spawn` function, which is higher level and offers more options. It safely uses `vfork` when possible, depending on the options you pass it. I have been able to use `posix_spawn` successfully and overcome that annoying "double memory checking issue" that `fork` + `exec` was giving me.

[A really good page on this topic, with links to some `posix_spawn` examples.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris10/subprocess-136439.html)

Comment: Incidentally, Java's `Runtime.exec()` has traditionally used `fork()/exec()`, but IIRC Java 1.7 will use `vfork()/exec()` or `posix_spawn()` where available.

Answer (score 4):

From my man page

> (From  POSIX.1)  The  vfork() function
>   has the same effect as fork(2), except
>   that the behavior is undefined if the
>   process created by
>          vfork() either modifies any data other than a variable of type
>   pid_t used to store the return value
>   from vfork(), or returns from  the
>          function in which vfork() was called, or calls any other function
>   before successfully calling _exit(2)
>   or one of the exec(3) family of
>          functions.
>
> vfork()  differs  from  fork(2)  in 
>   that the parent is suspended until the
>   child terminates (either normally, by
>   calling _exit(2), or
>          abnormally, after delivery of a fatal signal), or it makes a call to
>   execve(2).  Until that point, the
>   child shares  all  memory  with
>          its parent, including the stack.  The child must not return from
>   the current function or call exit(3),
>   but may call _exit(2).

Comment: +1 RTF man pages. Also, xkcd link since xkcd has a comic for *every* SO question: http://xkcd.org/293

Comment: Also worth noting that `vfork()` is mostly an historical artifact -- on modern systems with sane copy-on-write semantics, `vfork()` usually doesn't gain you much (if anything, sometimes it's essentially an alias for `fork()`!).

Answer (score 2):

Some systems have a system call vfork(), which was originally designed as a lower-overhead version of fork(). Since fork() involved copying the entire address space of the process, 
and was therefore quite expensive, the vfork() function was introduced (in 3.0BSD).

However, since vfork() was introduced, the implementation of fork() has improved drastically, most notably with the introduction of `copy-on-write', where the copying of the process address space is transparently faked by allowing both processes to refer to the same physical memory until either of them modify it. This largely removes the justification for vfork(); indeed, a large proportion of systems now lack the original functionality of 
vfork() completely. For compatibility, though, there may still be a vfork() call present, that simply calls fork() without attempting to emulate all of the vfork() semantics.

As a result, it is very unwise to actually make use of any of the differences between fork() and vfork(). Indeed, it is probably unwise to use vfork() at all, unless you know exactly why you want to.

The basic difference between the two is that when a new process is created with vfork(), the parent process is temporarily suspended, and the child process might borrow the parent's address space. This strange state of affairs continues until the child process 
either exits, or calls execve(), at which point the parent process continues.

This means that the child process of a vfork() must be careful to avoid unexpectedly modifying variables of the parent process. In particular, the child process must not return from the function containing the vfork() call, and it must not call exit() (if it needs to exit, it should use _exit(); actually, this is also true for the child of a normal fork()).

Answer (score 1):

Refer [here](http://www.unixguide.net/unix/programming/1.1.2.shtml) and from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28operating_system%29)-

> On some systems, vfork() is the same
>   as fork(). The vfork() function
>   differs from fork() only in that the
>   child process can share code and data
>   with the calling process (parent
>   process).

Answer (score 1):

**The basic difference between the two is that when a new process is created with `vfork()`, the parent process is temporarily suspended, and the child process might borrow the parent's address space. This strange state of affairs continues until the child process either exits, or calls `execve()`, at which point the parent process continues.**

This means that the child process of a `vfork()` must be careful to
avoid unexpectedly modifying variables of the parent process. In
particular, the child process must not return from the function
containing the `vfork()` call, and it must not call
`exit()` (if it needs to exit, it should use `_exit();`
actually, this is also true for the child of a normal `fork()`).

However, since `vfork()` was introduced, the
implementation of `fork()` has improved drastically, most notably
with the introduction of 'copy-on-write', **where the copying of the
process address space is transparently faked by allowing both processes
to refer to the same physical memory until either of them modify
it.** This largely removes the justification for `vfork();` indeed, a
large proportion of systems now lack the original functionality of
`vfork()` completely. For compatibility, though, there may still be
a `vfork()` call present, that simply calls `fork()` without
attempting to emulate all of the `vfork()` semantics.

As a result, it is very unwise to actually make use of any of the
differences between `fork()` and `vfork()`. Indeed, it is
probably unwise to use `vfork()` at all, unless you know exactly
why you want to.