# Why is clone() used and not fork()?

Tags: linux, unix, fork, system-calls, strace

I'm doing some work on pipes and forks.
I have this strace output, however i am unsure why clone is used and not fork. Does this mean they are the same?

Strace output

```
enter codexecve("./forks", ["./forks"], [/* 55 vars */]) = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f2b0e498700) = 0
pipe([3, 4])                            = 0
clone(Process 7304 attached
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f2b0e4989d0) = 7304
[pid  7303] execve("/usr/bin/wc", ["wc", "-l"], [/* 55 vars */] <unfinished ...>
[pid  7304] execve("/bin/ls", ["ls"], [/* 55 vars */] <unfinished ...>
[pid  7303] <... execve resumed> )      = 0
[pid  7304] <... execve resumed> )      = 0
[pid  7303] arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f558acde700) = 0
[pid  7304] arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f4bef4f67c0) = 0
[pid  7304] exit_group(0)               = ?
Process 7304 detached
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
21
exit_group(0)
```

Answer (score 5):

No, `fork()` and `clone()` aren't the same. However, you can imagine both of them as functions used as wrappers around `clone()` syscall, meaning that they use the same `clone()` syscall internally to create the new process. That explains what you observed on `strace`'s output.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18904292/2304215) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4856255/2304215) question; they explain the differences better than I could.