# Why is fork() accepted in strace if the actual syscall is clone()?

Tags: c, fork, system-calls, glibc, strace

I am using the following command to check the number of system calls during the execution of one of my programs:

`strace -e trace=<syscall> -c ./program [ARGS]`

If I substitute `<syscall>` with `fork()` it returns a total of 0 calls, as it is now implemented with `clone()`. However, if it returns 0 all the time, why is it still accepted as a system call? Isn't it just a wrapper for the actual syscall `clone()`?

I would expect the `strace` command to return an error for `trace=fork()` such as:

`strace: invalid system call 'fork'`

I just do not understand why it is still accepted as a valid parameter if it actually is just `clone()`. What am I missing? Why is it still accepted in `strace` if the parameter only accepts system calls?

Links I checked:

- [Fork() now calls clone() and is no longer a syscall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904292/is-it-true-that-fork-calls-clone-internally)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are confusing the C library function with the actual syscall. Since the `clone` syscall is more powerful and can always be used in place of `fork`, most C libraries have implemented the library function `fork()` in terms of the `clone` syscall. However, the `fork` syscall definitely still exists. This is because the kernel needs to guarantee backwards compatibility with older programs that use `fork`.

Internally, in terms of kernel code, `fork` is implemented as a call to `clone` (see e.g., the code [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.8/source/kernel/fork.c#L2991)), but it still exists. Therefore it makes sense that tools like `strace` still know about `fork` and allow you to filter for it. The only architecture I can think of where `fork` does not exist as a syscall is ARM64 with AArch64 ABI, which is "recent".