# Monitor commands that are executed in a shell in Linux and block some of them, using a user-mode app or kernel module?

Tags: linux, windows, security, kernel, driver

In windows, we can monitor executed command with various ways, such as monitoring process creations with a kernel driver callback and checking if the parent is CMD or powershell, then parsing its command line to see what command has been executed.

My question is, how to do this in linux? meaning how can i write a program that monitors every executed command in most of the common shells such as bin/sh, and blocks certain commands from getting executed via command line?

Is this possible with a user-mode app? if not, then how about a kernel module?

Edit 1:

Also note that it is really important to find the parent process that executed the command in this case, for example if a benign process executed command "X" it can be completely fine, but that same executable getting executed by something else might be extremely suspicious and needs to get blocked/reviewed. Basically what is the equivalent of PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx in Linux?

Comment: Most likely SELinux can help you

Comment: process creation syscalls are described here https://stackoverflow.com/q/4856255/1216776

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny I'm asking about writing a user mode or kernel module to solve this. Specifically for certain linux servers. we want to monitor any commands that are executed and block certain ones, for example in a ssh session. And we cant change them to SELinux.

Comment: @stark I'm asking about which APIs does linux provide in user-mode or kernel so i can monitor commands that are executed via different shells, for example in a ssh session, so i can block certain commands.

Comment: Users can be imaginative when it comes to cracking of the protection. suppose you want to block ```cp /etc/shadow ~/zzz``` command. Users could copy ```cp``` into ```zp``` and run it. they could use ```cat```, ```dd``` etc to do the same thing. Also they could uppload arbitrary binary via copy-paste with all logic being compiled into binary so command line would not show anything suspicious. Time works against you - you spend 20 hours on development of protection but users have years of tinkering. What I'm getting at is you should protect resourses instead of blocking some commands.

Comment: do you block if parent is a script?  do you block if parent called exec?  do you prevent user from making links? your method seems odd.

Comment: the standard way to do this is a chroot

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny It doesn't matter, we want to block command "x" at this point, worrying about how can it get bypassed is for later. In windows its really simple with a kernel driver, how it is done in Linux?

Comment: @stark What I'm asking is really simple, i want to block any user to execute command x, whether its from an ssh or a local user. In windows it has a very simple answer called PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx, what is the answer in Linux?

Comment: @stark  Also note that it is really important to get the parent process that executed the command in this case, for example if a benign process executed command "X" it can be completely fine, but that same executable getting executed by something else might be extremely suspicious and needs to get blocked/reviewed. Basically what is the equivalent of PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx in Linux?