# how to use correctly fork() and exec()

Tags: c, process, exec, fork

I have this code;

```
pid_t process;
process = fork();

if (process < 0){
   //fork error
   perror("fork");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (process == 0){
   //i try here the execl
   execl ("process.c", "process" , n, NULL);
}
else {
   wait(NULL);
}
```

I don't know if this use of `fork()` and `exec()` combined is correct. When I try to run the program from the bash I do not receive any result, so I thought it could be a problem in this part of code.
Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One problem is that

```
if (process = 0){
```

should read

```
if (process == 0){
```

Otherwise you're *assigning* zero to `process` and only calling `execl` if `result` is non-zero (i.e. never).

Also, you're trying to exec something called `process.c`. There's no doubt that one could have an executable called `process.c`. However, conventionally names ending in `.c` are given to C source code files. If `process.c` is indeed a C file, you need to compile and link it first.

Once you've built the executable, you need to either place it somewhere on `$PATH` or specify its full path to `execle()`. In many Unix environments placing it in the current directory won't be enough.

Finally, it's unclear what `n` is in the `execle()` call, but the name hints at a numeric variable. You need to make sure that it's a string and not, for example, an integer.

Comment: @Sorcipuppolo: You don't need to link it to your code, you just need to produce an executable. The compiler often calls the linker by default. E.g. with gcc you simply run `gcc -o process process.c` and you'll get an executable called `process`.

Comment: I made a makefile in which i compile all my functions, i have an executable called 'process'. But i don't know if it is enough. Is it possibile to pass numeric arguments in the ececl without a cast?

Comment: @Sorcipuppolo: A cast won't do you any good as it won't allocate memory for the string... you have to *convert* everything to strings.

Comment: execl ("/path/process", "/path/process", "5", NULL);

Comment: @aix:  But what if i need to pass a numeric argument? (Thanks a lot anyway for the help)

Comment: Just sprintf() your numeric to a string and use a pointer to the string.  You are setting up the command line for the exec-ed program.  All program arguments are strings.

Comment: @Duck: that's true, so i'll try to pass strings instead of integers and the path of my executable file, thanks

Answer (score -1):

Well as per the answers and comments above your code should look somewhat like this

```
pid_t process;
process = vfork(); //if your sole aim lies in creating a child that will ultimately call exec family functions then its advisable to use vfork

if (process < 0)
{
  //fork error
  perror("fork");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (process == 0)
{
  //i try here the execl
  char N[MAX_DIGITS];//A correction here
  itoa(n,N);//write this function yourself
  execl ("process", "process" , N, NULL);// Here process is the name of the executable N is your original argument
  fprintf(stderr,"execl failed\n");//check for error in execl

}
else
{
  wait(NULL);
}
```

Notice the use of vfork instead of fork.Its because it would be much more efficient.The reason could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259629/what-is-the-difference-between-fork-and-vfork)

Comment: As the child writes to `n` after `vfork()` the process runs into undefined behaviour. Use `fork()` if modify any variables before `exec*()`ing.