# Main Loop doesn't exit Normally

Tags: c, terminal, atexit

I have created this function which acts as the Main Menu for a Terminal-based application:

```
bool wizard_run() {
   char *command = NULL;
   bool repeat = false;
   bookmark:

   terminal_prepare();
   terminal_message(MESSAGE_INTRODUCTION);

   loop: /* repeat until a valid command */ {
      free(command); /* free any previous command */
      command = terminal_command(PROMPT_COMMAND, COMMAND_LENGTH, repeat);

      if (!strcmp(command, COMMAND_ENCRYPT)) wizard_encrypt();
      else if (!strcmp(command, COMMAND_DECRYPT)) wizard_decrypt();
      else if (!strcmp(command, COMMAND_CONCEAL)) wizard_conceal();
      else if (!strcmp(command, COMMAND_REVEAL)) wizard_reveal();
      else if (!strcmp(command, COMMAND_ERASE)) wizard_erase();
      else if (!strcmp(command, COMMAND_GENERATE)) wizard_generate();
      else if (!strcmp(command, COMMAND_NAVIGATE)) directory_navigate(RDS_HOME)
      else if (!strcmp(command, COMMAND_SESSION)) wizard_session();
      else if (!strcmp(command, COMMAND_SAFEMODE)) wizard_safemode();
      else if (!strcmp(command, COMMAND_HELP)) wizard_help(HELP_MAINMENU)
      else if (!strcmp(command, COMMAND_EXIT)) {free(command); return false;}
      else {repeat = true; goto loop;}
   }

   free(command); /* free last command */
   return true;
}
```

All capitalized Values are `#defined` constants, all `...(...)` are functions except `wizard_help(...)` and `directory_navigate(...)` which are macros (that's why there is no semicolon ending those lines).

This is the main function of the application:

```
void main() {
   // initialize any Components needed
   if (!directory_rdsload()) return;
   packager_reset();

   // show the Splash Screen
   SPLASH();

   // continuously execute the Main Thread
   while (wizard_run()); /* execution loop */

   // perform any Clean-UP needed before exit
   reset();
   encryption_reset();
   directory_reset(is_safemode);
}
```

Here, only `SPLASH()` is a macro.

All boolean values (i.e. `true`, `false`) are predefined unsigned char values, while `bool` is `typedef unsigned char bool;`.

The normal behaviour for it would be to exit the `wizard_run()` loop when the User inputs `exit` (the current value of COMMAND_EXIT), execute `reset(); encryption_reset(); directory_reset(is_safemode);` and then terminate the application normally. Instead, when I type `exit` for the first time, it re-displays the menu and when I type `exit` for a second time it terminates with the following error:

```
application: cxa_atexit.c:99: __new_exitfn: Assertion `l != ((void *)0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

When the program is run under `gdb`, I get this error:

```
application: cxa_atexit.c:99: __new_exitfn: Assertion `l != ((void *)0)' failed.

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0xb7fdd424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
```

No other function except `main()` ever calls `wizard_run()`, so this isn't the reason why the Menu is re-displayed instead of exiting. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!!! :D

Comment: Run this under a debugger, and when that assert fires I all-but-*guarantee* you will get a stack trace of *exactly* why this is happening. You have *way* too many function calls that we can't see code for (`terminal_command()` would be one that is highly suspect). And side note: that `goto` in `wizard_run()` is entirely unneeded; get rid of it and use a proper `while`-loop.

Comment: Function `terminal_command()` uses a `printf` and a `scanf` to print a prompt message and read user input (command). The last boolean determines whether to overwrite the previous prompt in the terminal or whether to go to a new line.

Comment: What I do is start the application and immediately type `exit`.

Comment: I'm hoping `terminal_command()` also allocates some memory as well.

Comment: Yes! It always allocates 256 bytes of memory and makes sure that any excess characters are discarded. That's why I call `free(command)`.

Comment: The error dump being shown looks to be because the exit-handler function chain is being overwritten when it shouldn't be. If this is happening without any of the other cruft in your program, start by commenting out the while-loop to `wizard_run()` in your main. If that "works" then bring it back and comment all junk in your loop out until only the exit-logic is left.. Keep adding back in one piece at a time until it reproduces. I'm confident either you or code your using is writing to memory in an undefined behavior manner, and as with all undefined behavior, it is *very* difficult to find.

Comment: And if your command reader is so simple, ***post it***.  If it isn't the source of the problem, so be it, but you have a **ton** of functions in here, any one of which could be causing the issue, and **none** of which we can see the code for. Without definitive code, the best you'll get is speculation, but nothing concrete.

Comment: Even that can guide me to the correct path! Did you say it was a actually a memory error? I'll try both your suggestions and post my progress. Thank you very much! :D

Comment: I have tested `terminal_command()` on its own using valgrind; it works fine. I have been trying to find the error for some hours now (since before posting the question) and - after your advice - isolated SPLASH. It is defined as: `#define SPLASH() {if (!vfork()) execlp("/bin/splash", "/bin/splash", NULL); else wait();}`. The problem seems to lie there. Could anyone explain what is going wrong? :S

Comment: Suspect after `command = terminal_command(...)`, you want `repeat = false;`.  I think once `repeat` gets set, your terminal_command() behaves differently.

Answer (score 0):

OK, eventually I found the problem! It was located within `SPLASH()`. This is a macro defined as:

```
#define SPLASH() { \
   if (!vfork()) execlp("/bin/splash", "/bin/splash", NULL); \
   else wait(); \
}
```

Due to the fact that my application is still at the stage of testing, I didn't put `splash` in directory `/bin`. I never thought this could be a problem. However, there is a catch here: I use `vfork` instead of `fork`, as I only want to execute a new program (`vfork` is faster when you don't need the Child to be a copy of the Parent process). As no `/bin/bash` existed, execlp didn't load the new application image for the Child Process. Thus, I can imagine that both processes were sharing a part of their Images? ([look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259629/what-is-the-difference-between-fork-and-vfork))

So, when `SPLASH()` is called, the Child process takes over and displays the Main Menu again. Everything looks fine. But when I call `exit`, the Child terminates normally and the Parent takes control of the Terminal and re-displays the Main Menu (that's why it is displayed twice!). When `exit` is called once again, it is the Parent process' turn to terminate. However, the Child process - which had been sharing the same process image as the Parent - has already terminated, thus altering some data. It must have been this altered data that caused the error on exit.

As my functions clear the terminal and write over the previous messages, I couldn't notice the Child process displaying the Main Menu at the first place! ;)

I'm really excited about the nature of the whole problem. Although I couldn't explain it better (I must have made some mistakes in my terminology), I hope you understand what went wrong! Thanks everyone for your useful comments (especially WhozCraig)!!! :D