# Multi threading with vfork

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, fork, pipe

I have a problem with my code and this is the first time im using fork. As soon as i Use piping or vfork, My child processors go on series rather than parallel. i get my answer i expected but program does not do what i want.

My basic Program just calculates the sum of 1 to 100000000, 1+2+3+4...10000 etc.

I just wanted to learn fork and piping and benchmark them.

Here is my code and sorry for messy code and my comments. This is my testing code so I made a big mess.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <csignal>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main () {

    long sumTemp =0;
    long sum = 0;
    long times = 1000000000; // number to add up
    int threads = 4;
    long amount[threads];
    pid_t childPids[threads];
    pid_t p;
    time_t tstart, tend;
    long lastNumber=0;
    long addedValue =0;
    int fd[2];
    long readbuffer = 0;
    int number = 0;

// Counting time

    tstart = time(0);

    for (int p=0; p<=threads; p++){
            amount[p]=0;
    }

//Having the task divided to threads

    long divided = (times/threads);
    for (int j=1; j<=threads; j++){
            addedValue += divided;
            amount[j]= addedValue;
            cout << amount[j-1] << " .... " << j << " ... " << amount[j] << endl;

    }

    // Child making

    for (int j=0; j<threads; j++){

            // running fork
            pipe(fd);
            p = vfork();

            if (p== -1)
            {
                    printf("Error occoured with fork()\n");
                    exit(99);                       // exit status 99
            }

            else if (p == 0){

                    //calculation

                    cout << " child : " << j << " " << p <<endl;

                    for (long i=(amount[j]+1); i<=amount[j+1]; i++){
                            sumTemp += i;

                    }

                    exit(0);
            }
            else {

                    childPids[j] = p;
                    sum = sumTemp;

            }

    }

    for(int k = 0; k < threads; k++){
    waitpid(childPids[k], NULL, WNOHANG);
    }

    tend = time(0);
    cout << endl << " Sum of adding " << times << "." << endl;
    cout << " Sum : " << sum << endl;
    cout << " It took " << difftime(tend, tstart) << " second(s)."
    << endl << endl;
}
```

`

Comment: You managed to learn abount ecurrence relation relations? - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation - Can be replaced by a simple equation.

Comment: @Hands - The solution is easy. `1+2+...+n = (n+n*n)/2`

Comment: @Ed Heal - What im trying to do is just benchmark them and divide the program, not about the best way to calculate. And i do know about easy math behind it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fork()`, not `vfork()`. `vfork()` should only be used if the child process is going to call `exec()` shortly after being started. `vfork()` suspends the parent process until the child exits or calls `exec()`.

[What is the difference between fork() and vfork()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259629/what-is-the-difference-between-fork-and-vfork)

Comment: thanks for the reply but I used fork() with pipe to share the data with parent but i have the same issue.

Comment: @EdHeal i do, but im new to the parallel processing. A good direction would help

Comment: @Hans - There are a lot of tutorials on-line for multi-threaded programming. Google them. It is a very large subject area for this forum. Perhaps `pthread` would be a goodish starting point. As to theory look up semaphores, message queues, mutual exclusion.