# fork vs vfork functionality in a C program

Tags: c, fork, vfork

I am doing some C exercise for self-learning, and came across the following problem:

Part a:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {                                         

    int a = 5, b = 8;                                                     
    int v;                                                                

    v = fork();                                                           
    if(v == 0) {                                                          
        // 10                                                             
        a = a + 5;                                                        
        // 10                                                             
        b = b + 2;                                                        
        exit(0);                                                          
    }                                                                     
    // Parent code                                                        
    wait(NULL);                                                           
    printf("Value of v is %d.\n", v); // line a                           
    printf("Sum is %d.\n", a + b); // line b                              
    exit(0);                                                              

}
```

Part b:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {                                         

    int a = 5, b = 8;                                                     
    int v;                                                                

    v = vfork();                                                               
    if(v == 0) {                                                          
        // a = 10                                                         
        a = a + 5;                                                        
        // b = 6                                                          
        b = b - 2;                                                        
        exit(0);                                                          
    }                                                                     
    // Parent code                                                        
    wait(NULL);                                                           
    printf("Value of v is %d.\n", v); // line a                           
    printf("Sum is %d.\n", a + b); // line b                              
    exit(0);                                                              

}
```

We have to compare the outputs of `line a` and `line b`.

The outputs of part a is:

```
Value of v is 79525.
Sum is 13.
```

The outputs of part b is:

```
Value of v is 79517.
Sum is 16.
```

It appears in part a, the sum is the sum of the initial declaration of `a` and `b`, whereas in part b, the sum include the summation within the child process.

My question is - why is this happening?

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29310118/1913389):

> The basic difference between the two is that when a new process is
>   created with vfork(), the parent process is temporarily suspended, and
>   the child process might borrow the parent's address space. This
>   strange state of affairs continues until the child process either
>   exits, or calls execve(), at which point the parent process continues.

The definition of parent process is temporarily suspended doesn't make much sense to me. Does this mean that for `1b`, the program waits until the child process to finish running (hence why the child process variables get summed) before the parent runs?

The problem statement also assumes that "the process ID of the parent process maintained by the kernel is `2500`, and that the new processes are created by the operating system before the child process is created."

By this definition, what would the value of `v` for both programs be?

Comment: "The `vfork()` function shall be equivalent to `fork()`, except that the behavior is undefined if the process created by `vfork()` [...] modifies any data other than a variable of type `pid_t` used to store the return value from `vfork()`" - this question is another instance of "the behavior of my code is undefined, but why does it do *this particular* thing?"

Comment: After `vfork`, the parent is suspended until the child calls an `exec*` function or until it `_exit`s, whichever happens first. In a regular fork, you won't get variable rewriting at all because each process will have their own copy.

Comment: @PSkocik thank you for this answer. If I am understanding this correctly, `fork()` spawns a separate copy, which is why `a` and `b` retains their initialization values and don't get written. For `vfork()`, the child executes, which is why the summation happens within the child.

Comment: If you are curious about `vfork`, it's purpose is to be used in fork/exec to launch a new program but without copying the original program's memory. This was important in OS's that had to copy memory pages instead of marking them for COW. It is still important today on operating systems configured to disable memory overcommit. On Linux without overcommit, a 2 GB Java process using fork/exec would require 2 GB free RAM. vfork/exec will not.

Comment: when calling the system function: fork() or vfork(),  there are three outcomes.   1) the function failed, in which case a -1 is returned  2) the function was successful and the parent is executing (returns pid of child)  3) the function was successful and the child is executing (returned pid of 0)  When calling either of those functions, the code should check for all three conditions, not just the 'success' conditions.\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the parent process is temporarily suspended

Basically, the parent process will not run until the child calls either `_exit` or one of the `exec` functions.  In your example this means the child will run and therefore perform the summation before the parent runs and does the prints.

As for:

> My question is - why is this happening?

First, your part b has undefined behavior because you are violating the `vfork` semantics.  Undefined behavior for a program means the program will not behave in a predictable manner. See [this SO post on undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) for more details (it includes some C++ but most of the ideas are the same). From the [POSIX specs on `vfork`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/vfork.html):

> The vfork() function has the same effect as fork(2), except that the
>   behavior is undefined if the process created by vfork() either
>   modifies any data other than a variable of type pid_t used to store
>   the return value from vfork(), or returns from the function in which
>   vfork() was called, or calls any other function before successfully
>   calling _exit(2) or one of the exec(3) family of functions.

So your part b could really do anything.  However, you will probably see a somewhat consistent output from part b.  This is because when you use `vfork` you are not creating a new address space.  Instead, the child process basically "borrows" the address space of the parent, usually with the intent that it will call one of the `exec` functions and create a new program image.  Instead in your part b you are using the parent address space.  Basically, after the child has called `exit` (which is also invalid as it should call `_exit`) `a` most likely will equal 10 and `b` will most likely equal 6 **in the parent**.  Therefore, the summation is 16 as shown in part b.  I say *most likely* because as stated before this program has undefined behavior.

For part a where `fork` is used the child gets its own address space and its modifications are not seen in the parent, therefore the value printed is 13 (5 + 8).

Finally with regards to the value of `v`, this is seems just to be something the question is stating to make the output it is showing make sense.  The value of `v` could be any valid value returned by `vfork` or `fork` and does not have to be limited to 2500.

Comment: This is a terrific answer, thank you. Can you describe what you mean by "undefined behavior"? Does this mean the program is wrong? Or missing information?

Comment: the 'exit' function works just fine and is actually better because it does clean up by closing files, etc. while the _exit and _Exit functions do not close files, do not call 'atexit()' functions, etc.

Comment: @user3629249 Actually, the spec says calling any function but _exit and the exec variants is undefined behavior and the reasons you just stated are why it is bad.  The child doesn't have its own address space so it will be doing cleanup on the parent's memory, such as flushing buffers which really belong to the parent.