# How do Multi-process use the same ncurses screen?

Tags: c++, multiprocessing, ncurses

I'm writing a c++ multi-process program with ncurses.

Each process is required to display something on the screen.

My Example code:

```
int main() {
  initscr();
  noecho();
  curs_set(0);

  int flag = fork();
  if (flag == -1)
    exit(1);
  else if (flag == 0) {
    WINDOW *win = newwin(4, 4, 0, 0);
    int n = 0;
    while (1) {
      mvwprintw(win, 0, 0, "%d", n % 9);
      wrefresh(win);
      n = (n + 1) % 9;
      sleep(1);
    }
  }
  else {
    WINDOW *win = newwin(4, 4, 8, 8);
    int n = 0;
    while (1) {
      mvwprintw(win, 0, 0, "%d", n % 9);
      wrefresh(win);
      n = (n + 1) % 9;
      sleep(1);
    }
  }
  endwin();

  return 0;
}
```

But it can only display one process's information on the screen.

How can I solve it?

Comment: You probably want threads rather than separate processes.

Comment: Using threads can work, Thanks. But it's a homework required  using multi-process to implement. ^_^ @πάνταῥεῖ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have hacked about something ugly that roughly works but shows what the problems are. I suspect a single window manager process which other processes communicate with would be better - or some horrible set of mutexes.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <curses.h>
int main() {
  initscr();
  noecho();
  curs_set(0);
    WINDOW *win0 = newwin(4, 4, 0, 0);
    WINDOW *win1 = newwin(4, 4, 8, 8);

  int flag = fork();
  if (flag == -1)
    exit(1);
  else if (flag == 0) {
    int n = 0;
    while (1) {
      mvwprintw(win0, 0, 0, "%d", n % 9);
      wrefresh(win0);
      wrefresh(win1);
      n = (n + 1) % 9;
      sleep(1);
    }
  }
  else {
    int n = 0;
    while (1) {
      mvwprintw(win1, 0, 0, "%d", n % 9);
      wrefresh(win1);
      wrefresh(win0);
      n = (n + 1) % 9;
      sleep(1);
    }
  }
  endwin();

  return 0;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The example creates two 4x4 windows, with the second offset to 8,8.  So they have no *lines* in common.

Since you're using *fork* (rather than *vfork*), the two processes should have separate address spaces, and there should be no way for one process to *refresh* a window which is *modified* in the other process.  In some cases, developers have chosen to equate `vfork` and `fork`.  With Linux, the [vfork manual page comments](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vfork.2.html):

> Standard Description
>   (From POSIX.1) The **`vfork()`** function has the  same  effect  as  **`fork(2)`**,
>   except that the behavior is ***undefined*** if the process created by **`vfork()`**
>   either modifies any data other than a variable of type  **`pid_t`**  used  to
>   store  the  return  value from **`vfork()`**, or returns from the function in
>   which **`vfork()`** was called, or calls any other function  before  successfully calling **`_exit(2)`** or one of the **`exec(3)`** family of functions.

but goes on to say

> The requirements put on **`vfork()`** by the standards are ***weaker*** than
>   those put on **`fork(2)`**, so an implementation where the two are
>   synonymous is ***compliant***.  In particular, the programmer cannot rely
>   on the parent remaining blocked until the child either terminates or
>   calls ***execve(2)***, and cannot rely on any specific behavior with
>   respect to shared memory.

That *weaker* and *compliant* is a developer arguing that making the two functions similar doesn't really matter...

The [fork manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) asserts that there are separate address spaces:

> The child process and the parent process run in ***separate memory
>   spaces***.  At the time of **`fork()`** both memory spaces have the same
>   content.  Memory writes, file mappings (**`mmap(2)`**), and unmappings
>   (**`munmap(2)`**) performed by one of the processes do not affect the
>   other.

but we're left with that ambiguity in the description of `vfork`.  Your program may fail to update the window belonging to the parent process as part of this `vfork` behavior — and refreshing *both* windows in the suggested answer merely confirms that the `fork` function is `vfork` in disguise.

POSIX currently has no page for `vfork`.  It had [one here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/vfork.html) (the [`fork`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) description is worth reading).

Either way, using `vfork` wouldn't actually improve things.  If you have to work within the same address space, that's what threads are for.  If you have to use separate processes, making one process update the screen and other process(es) communicate with pipes is what people actually do.

A commented suggested that `fork` is obsolete.  POSIX has something different to say on that aspect.  Quoting from the rationale for [`posix_spawn`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html#tag_16_371_08):

> The posix_spawn() function and its close relation posix_spawnp() have been introduced to overcome the following perceived difficulties with fork(): the fork() function is difficult or impossible to implement without swapping or dynamic address translation.
>
> - Swapping is generally too slow for a realtime environment.
> - Dynamic address translation is not available everywhere that POSIX might be useful.
> - Processes are too useful to simply option out of POSIX whenever it must run without address translation or other MMU services.
>
> Thus, POSIX needs process creation and file execution primitives that can be efficiently implemented without address translation or other MMU services.
>
> The posix_spawn() function is implementable as a library routine, but both posix_spawn() and posix_spawnp() are designed as kernel operations. Also, although they may be an efficient replacement for many fork()/ exec pairs, their goal is to provide useful process creation primitives for systems that have difficulty with fork(), ***not to provide drop-in replacements for fork()/ exec.***

Further reading:

- [what is the difference between fork() and vfork()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259629/what-is-the-difference-between-fork-and-vfork)
- [The difference between fork(), vfork(), exec() and clone()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856255/the-difference-between-fork-vfork-exec-and-clone)
- [EWONTFIX - vfork considered dangerous](https://ewontfix.com/7/)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain it.

Comment: Re: POSIX and `vfork()`. `vfork()` was obsoleted by POSIX 2008, and anything that used `vfork() + execve()` should better use `posix_spawn()`.

Comment: I use `fork()` without `exec()` a lot. I certainly hope it is not going to become obsolete. It's extremely useful in a server. You `listen()` and on an `accept()` you `fork()` or even better, you `fork()` and each child process calls `listen()` + `accept()`. The `exec()` breaks that scheme and makes it impossible to get such an optimization (Apache uses that `fork()` + `listen()` scheme and that's one reason for its good speed.)