# File descriptor table for vfork vs. fork

Tags: c, linux, fork, system, vfork

I am a newbie in System Programming and I encounter some misunderstanding in fork and vfork.

- From my knowledge, fork duplicate parent process's process and child process has its own VM and own file descriptor table.
- As for vfork, it shared parent process's VM but child process will has its own file descriptor table.

---

So here comes the problem:

1. As child process share parent process' address, why does it need its own file descriptor table?
2. Where will the variable be stored if I declare one in the child process? (Will it use the space of parent process)
   Thanks a lot.

Comment: Consider `vfork` as obsolete. In 2020 there is not reason to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Because it's common to redirect `stdin` and/or `stdout` before calling `exec` in the child process. If they shared the same file descriptor table, this would modify the parent process's I/O.
2. You shouldn't store any variables in the child process. `vfork()` should only be used if you're going to immediately call an `exec` function.

Note that `vfork()` is obsolete on modern operating systems. Instead of copying the address space they use copy-on-write.

For more information see [What is the difference between fork() and vfork()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259629/what-is-the-difference-between-fork-and-vfork)